# yii cant create new instance of class

Tags: php, yii

In my view im trying to do :

`$accountLogin = new AccountLogin;`

which should create a new instance of that class which is defined in my vendor libraries.

```
class AccountLogin extends CFormModel
{
..
}
```

But I'm getting `unable to open stream('AccountLogin')`.

What am I doing wrong? Is there somewhere I am supposed to specify where the directory is located at?

Comment: you should import this file first, put it in components folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to import your class first .

the beast and easy way to import any class in yii is put it in component like these :

Class:

```
class RegionSingleton extends CApplicationComponent
{
    private $_model=null;


    public function setModel($id)
    {
        $this->_model=Region::model()->findByPk($id);
    }

    public function getModel()
    {
        if (!$this->_model)
        {
            if (isset($_GET['region']))
                $this->_model=Region::model()->findByAttributes(array('url_name'=> $_GET['region']));
            else
                $this->_model=Region::model()->find();
        }
        return $this->_model;
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->model->id;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->model->name;
    }
}
```

And include this class in config main then you can call it in fast way in all your app:

```
'components'=>array(
        'region'=>array('class'=>'RegionSingleton'),
         ...
        )
```

Now, we can call it like this :

```
Yii::app()->region->model;
```

for have the model, or also

```
Yii::app()->region->id
```

for retrieve the id.

We can also set the model by using

```
Yii::app()->region->setModel($id)
```

Reference :
[link1](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/187/how-to-write-a-simple-application-component/)